# Catching a jira-python exception

Tags: python, jira, python-3.3, python-jira

I am trying to handle jira-python exception but my try, except does not seem to catch it. I also need to add more lines in order to be able to post this. So there they are, the lines.

```
try:
    new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
    stdout.write(str(new_issue.id))
except jira.exceptions.JIRAError:
    stdout.write("JIRAError")
    exit(1)
```

Here is the code that raises the exception:

```
import json


class JIRAError(Exception):
    """General error raised for all problems in operation of the client."""
    def __init__(self, status_code=None, text=None, url=None):
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.text = text
        self.url = url

    def __str__(self):
        if self.text:
            return 'HTTP {0}: "{1}"\n{2}'.format(self.status_code, self.text, self.url)
        else:
            return 'HTTP {0}: {1}'.format(self.status_code, self.url)


def raise_on_error(r):
    if r.status_code >= 400:
        error = ''
        if r.text:
            try:
                response = json.loads(r.text)
                if 'message' in response:
                    # JIRA 5.1 errors
                    error = response['message']
                elif 'errorMessages' in response and len(response['errorMessages']) > 0:
                    # JIRA 5.0.x error messages sometimes come wrapped in this array
                    # Sometimes this is present but empty
                    errorMessages = response['errorMessages']
                    if isinstance(errorMessages, (list, tuple)):
                        error = errorMessages[0]
                    else:
                        error = errorMessages
                elif 'errors' in response and len(response['errors']) > 0:
                    # JIRA 6.x error messages are found in this array.
                    error = response['errors']
                else:
                    error = r.text
            except ValueError:
                error = r.text
        raise JIRAError(r.status_code, error, r.url)
```

Comment: My biggest problem with this library is no one seems to know how to use it!  Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm not answering the question, but I feel I need to warn people that could get confused by that code (as I did)...
Maybe you are trying to write your own version of jira-python or it's an old version?

In any case, [here](http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/jira/exceptions.html#JIRAError) the link to the jira-python code for the JIRAError class
and [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-developer-faq/http-response-code-definitions) the list of codes

to catch the exception from that package I use the below code

```
from jira import JIRA, JIRAError
try:
   ...
except JIRAError as e:
   print e.status_code, e.text
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it is obvious and that's why you don't have it in your code paste, just in case, you do have

```
from jira.exceptions import JIRAError
```

somewhere in your code right?

Don't have enough reputation for comments so I'll add it answer for @arynhard:
I found the docs very light in particular in terms of example, you might find the scripts in this repo useful since they're all leveraging jira-python in someway or another.
https://github.com/eucalyptus/jira-scripts/

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but looks like you're catching `jira.exceptions.JIRAError`, while raising `JIRAError` - those are different types. You need to either remove "`jira.exceptions.`" part from your `except` statement, or raise `jira.exceptions.JIRAError` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's a very old one but I faced the same problem and this page is still showing up.

Here is how I trap the Exception, I used the Exception object.

```
 try:
        issue = jira.issue('jira-1')
 except  Exception as e:
        if 'EXIST' in e.text:
                print 'The issue does not exist'
                exit(1)
```

regards